# turn side nav-bar into top-bar when resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, navbar

Hey everyone I have a site that explains what I'm trying to accomplish, any help to find a good tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

if you go here and resize the page you'll see the side bar turn into a top bar. how can i do that?

http://portlanddecorating.co.uk/

I haven't found any tutorials for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you mean how they switch from the side nav to the "hamburger" menu - that's built in to BS 3 and 4 and is based on media query breakpoints.  Just design a vertical `navbar` and see what happens when you resize the window

Answer (score 0):

And because a visual example speaks louder than words...

Here is one way to create a vertical navbar.  note the media queries need to be adjusted based on the `navbar-expand-<size>` class used in the navbar tag `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm ...`

See [Bootstrap 4 Responsive breaks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) for more

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .vertiNav {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .vertiNav nav.navbar {
    flex-direction: column !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .vertiNav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vertiNav nav.navbar {
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="vertiNav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav flex-column">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to send this to me! this really help me out. I've been stuck on this for a couple of day.

Comment: Bootstrap is very versatile once you dive in.